# R unable to load internet routines after cmake installation

Tags: r, ggplot2, cmake

My Rstudio was working perfectly fine today until I had to install a package which required cmake.

Now I am getting an error whenever I open R studios:

`Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : internet routines cannot be loaded`

Because of this, no matter what package I try to install, I always get the following error:

`Warning in install.packages : unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: internet routines cannot be loaded Installing package into ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages : unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: internet routines cannot be loaded Warning in install.packages : package ‘ggpubr’ is not available for this version of R`

This happened only AFTER the cmake installation which required sudo privileges so the IT guy did it for me.

I have done a google search but most of the responses do not seem to be relevant to me - I haven't recently updated R or RStudio, nor have I updated anything in conda...some other information on google seemed to be very specific to certain packages which are irrelevant to me...

Running `conda install libssh2 krb5` did not help, nor did changing the repository. Running `capabilities()["libcurl"]`  produces `TRUE` and there is no problem with the library path.

`$ uname -a Linux r-233-g05 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

R version:
`$ R --version R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid" Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)`

When I open R and try to list the available packages:
`> available.packages() Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: internet routines cannot be loaded Package Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation File Repository`